I have a problem with assigning data returned from the backend to a variable of array data type in angular
I have an interface file as follows:
[and service file code image as follows](https://i.sstatic.net/2f0bzkDM.png)
and finally the function executes the request to get data from the backend and assign it to the variable users, then I get the following error](https://i.sstatic.net/AJ3cevH8.png)
nodejs backend works normally
I tried many ways but without success
I have a problem with assigning data returned from the backend to a variable of array data type so that I can iterate over that array and print the data in hmtl.
Detailed code image and error below, someone help me

Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example by providing the code as snippets but not images.

@noname please share the API response sample, to check

The API returns an object with a property data which contains list of users and not just a single user, so you need to configure the service API, to return a interface the same structure as the api response
Outside of the service add the below code
export interface UserResponse{
     data: User[];
}

Then use this interface to define the type of response from the api call
getUser(url: string): Observable<UserResponse> {
    return this.http.get<UserResponse>(url);
}

Since you are getting the API response as {data: Array(1)}, we have to access the inner data property for it to work in *ngFor
showUser() {
     this.services.getUser('...'). subscribe((response: UserResponse) => {
        this.users = response.data;
     });
}


I tried following your instructions and when the old error was fixed, the browser reported another error as follows  :  ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed. How can i fix it

@noname please share the API response and html code also

api return has the form:{data: Array(1)}
and here is my html code: <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
{{ user.id }}
{{ user.username }}
{{ user.name }}
{{ user.createAt }}

it not work:  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'User[]'

@noname we have to create a interface which tells typescript exactly what comes from the api call, plz check my updated answer

It's great that the above method works, but we are required to use 2 api services

@noname use the same method and try to solve the problem, create an interface the same structure as the api response and map it to the places you use the api
